# Explain slow Mercurial clone?

Tags: mercurial

Is there a way to determine why a given repository takes a long time to clone?

I'm guessing at some point we added some big files which we then deleted, and downloading this history probably causes the clone to be so slow.

We're not sure which files they are and if we could actually (permanently) delete them from the repo.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

you can't alter history of repo but you can create a new repo with selective history in it using hg convert, but *this will require everyone switching to the new repo* which may or may not be an issue for you depending how the project is run.

to use hg convert to strip a file create a file `filemap` with the following contents

```
exclude path/to/really/big/file
```

then run the command

```
hg convert --filemap filemap oldrepo newrepo
```

If you haven't had many deletes you may be able to find it with:

```
hg log --template "{file_dels} "
```

which will show all the files deleted for all commits

Answer (score 0):

You can just look inside .hg/store/data and see if there are any suspiciously large files.

Comment: @Marcus You cant delete files from the .hg/store directory, since there files are referenced by at least one head of your repo.

Comment: You cannot remove it from the existing changesets, but you can alter history if you really need to get rid of it.

Comment: @Ringding: Altering history will only work for one repository. Once a change has been shared with others, you're going to have a beast of a time making sure everybody removes those historical changes from their individual repositories.

Comment: Yes, that’s a well-known fact with DVCS.